# CSS: Remove outer spacing from container when dealing with columns

Tags: css

Is there a "right" way to remove the spacing on the sides, without having to hardcode each image with a specific padding on each side?

I am trying to make the images below the text span all the way to the borders to match the text above. In order to keep them all with the same separation, I am using padding, in this case 16px.

If I do (on the container):

```
margin: 0 -16px
```

the images will be aligned to the left side, but on the right side it will have double the space, in this case: 32px.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, Please share your HTML and CSS code or website link.Did you try setting width:99vw; on the container?

Comment: Please provide HTML demonstrating the issue you are facing, images doesn't help figuring out the issue in you CSS/HTML.

Comment: Thanks! I added a screenshot of the html.